# playwright failed to capture text

Tags: playwright

I'm a new comer to Javascript and Playwright. I followed the first example in the [Getting Started](https://playwright.dev/docs/intro/) guide with the following code:

```js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('basic test', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
    const title = page.locator('.navbar__inner.navbar__title');
    await expect(title).toHaveText('Playwright');
});
```

However, when I ran the test, `title` ends up being an empty string:

```
$ npx playwright test

Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✘  tests/example.spec.js:3:1 › basic test (6s)


  1) tests/example.spec.js:3:1 › basic test ========================================================

    Error: expect(received).toHaveText(expected)

    Expected string: "Playwright"
    Received string: ""

    Call log:
      - waiting for selector ".navbar__inner.navbar__title"


      4 |     await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
      5 |     const title = page.locator('.navbar__inner.navbar__title');
    > 6 |     await expect(title).toHaveText('Playwright');
        |                         ^
      7 | });
      8 |
      9 |

        at /Users/h.vu/Downloads/node/playwright/tests/example.spec.js:6:25
        at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
        at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:437:9)
        at WorkerRunner._runTestWithBeforeHooks (/Users/h.vu/Downloads/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/workerRunner.js:499:7)


  1 failed
    tests/example.spec.js:3:1 › basic test =========================================================
```

The call log, according to the output said, *waiting for selector ".navbar__inner.navbar__title"*, which I think this could be a timing issue. I appreciate your help to get this test up and running. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need empty space in locator:

```
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test.only ('basic test', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
    const title = page.locator('.navbar__inner .navbar__title');
    await expect(title).toHaveText('Playwright');
});
```

`('.navbar__inner .navbar__title');` has empty space between

Comment: This is right on the money. Thank you.